# Deserializing JSON with leading @ chars in servicestack

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, servicestack-text

The below snippet replicates a deserialisation issue I'm having inside a ServiceStack application. 
On running the below, the consignee property is populated correctly but the id is not.

```
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"@id\":\"abcd\",\"consignee\":\"mr mann\"}"; 
        shipment some_shipment = new shipment();
        some_shipment = json.FromJson<shipment>();
        Console.Read();
    }

    class shipment
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string consignee { get; set; }
    }
```

The library that is generating the JSON prefixes some elements with an @ to indicate that they came from an XML attribute but this program is beyond my control.
I understand that ServiceStack name matches between JSON and object properties.

I've tried appending an @ to the property name but that doesn't help.

```
//doesn't help
public string @id { get; set;}
```

Is there a way of telling ServiceStack to deserialise @id into id without going through the process of implementing a custom deserialiser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `[DataMember]` attribute to tell ServiceStack the name of the field to serialise into. When you do this you will be using a `[DataContract]` which then requires that all other fields are marked with `[DataMember]` to be included. I.e. they become opt-in.

So your `Shipping` class becomes:

```cs
[DataContract]
class shipment
{
    [DataMember(Name="@id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string consignee { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to reference [`using System.Runtime.Serialization;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

I hope that helps.